# testing api-platform always results on 404

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6

I have started a new project with symfony 6 and api-platform 2.6.8, in a very simple way and I have added some entities to test.

```sh
symfony new testapi
cd testapi
composer req api
composer req symfony/apache-pack
composer req --dev symfony/maker-bundle
composer req --dev test
composer req --dev symfony/browser-kit symfony/http-client
composer req --dev symfony/profiler-pack
```

I had created an entity called feriado and then I have manually tested with curl and swagger witout any errors.
[image]

The problem is when I execute a test
Seems like when phpunit is executed, no routes are available.
May be a problem of test environment?
I am lost at this point

```php
<?php
namespace App\Tests\functional;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;

class FeriadoTest extends ApiTestCase
{

    public function testFeriado() : void
    {
        $response = self::createClient()->request(
            'GET',
            'http://localhost/qapip/api/feriados', [
            'headers' => [
                'accept' => 'application/json'
                ],
            ]);

            $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(200);
    }

}
```

this is the answer no matter what

```json
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
  "title": "Anerroroccurred",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "No route found for \"GET http://localhost/qapip/api/feriado\"",
  "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
  "trace": [
    {
      "namespace": "",
      "short_class": "",
      "class": "",
      "type": "",
      "function": "",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php",
      "line": 130,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener",
      "short_class": "RouterListener",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "onKernelRequest",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php",
      "line": 111,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug",
      "short_class": "WrappedListener",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "__invoke",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php",
      "line": 230,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher",
      "short_class": "EventDispatcher",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "callListeners",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php",
      "line": 59,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher",
      "short_class": "EventDispatcher",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "dispatch",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php",
      "line": 152,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug",
      "short_class": "TraceableEventDispatcher",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "dispatch",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
      "line": 128,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
      "short_class": "HttpKernel",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "handleRaw",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
      "line": 74,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
      "short_class": "HttpKernel",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "handle",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php",
      "line": 202,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
      "short_class": "Kernel",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "handle",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernelBrowser.php",
      "line": 65,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
      "short_class": "HttpKernelBrowser",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernelBrowser",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "doRequest",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/KernelBrowser.php",
      "line": 171,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle",
      "short_class": "KernelBrowser",
      "class": "Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\KernelBrowser",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "doRequest",
      "file": "/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/AbstractBrowser.php",
      "line": 370,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\BrowserKit",
      "short_class": "AbstractBrowser",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\BrowserKit\\AbstractBrowser",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "request",
      "file": "/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Client.php",
      "line": 123,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Bridge\\Symfony\\Bundle\\Test",
      "short_class": "Client",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Bridge\\Symfony\\Bundle\\Test\\Client",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "request",
      "file": "/tests/functional/FeriadoTest.php",
      "line": 25,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "App\\Tests\\functional",
      "short_class": "FeriadoTest",
      "class": "App\\Tests\\functional\\FeriadoTest",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "testprueba",
      "file": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php",
      "line": 1545,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "PHPUnit\\Framework",
      "short_class": "TestCase",
      "class": "PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "runTest",
      "file": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php",
      "line": 1151,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "PHPUnit\\Framework",
      "short_class": "TestCase",
      "class": "PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "runBare",
      "file": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php",
      "line": 726,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "PHPUnit\\Framework",
      "short_class": "TestResult",
      "class": "PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestResult",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "run",
      "file": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php",
      "line": 903,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "PHPUnit\\Framework",
      "short_class": "TestCase",
      "class": "PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "run",
      "file": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php",
      "line": 677,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "PHPUnit\\Framework",
      "short_class": "TestSuite",
      "class": "PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestSuite",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "run",
      "file": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php",
      "line": 677,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "PHPUnit\\Framework",
      "short_class": "TestSuite",
      "class": "PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestSuite",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "run",
      "file": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php",
      "line": 677,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "PHPUnit\\Framework",
      "short_class": "TestSuite",
      "class": "PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestSuite",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "run",
      "file": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php",
      "line": 670,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "PHPUnit\\TextUI",
      "short_class": "TestRunner",
      "class": "PHPUnit\\TextUI\\TestRunner",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "run",
      "file": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php",
      "line": 143,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "PHPUnit\\TextUI",
      "short_class": "Command",
      "class": "PHPUnit\\TextUI\\Command",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "run",
      "file": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php",
      "line": 96,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "PHPUnit\\TextUI",
      "short_class": "Command",
      "class": "PHPUnit\\TextUI\\Command",
      "type": "::",
      "function": "main",
      "file": "/bin/phpunit",
      "line": 11,
      "args": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I use this using symfony server and it works maybe something wrong with your Apache Server configuration

Comment: make sense, since I had start symfony server and I change the test to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api and now I have an error that says that can't connect to the database.   
don´t know why, because it works on the browser
hydra:title":"An error occurred","hydra:description":"An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user

Comment: creating myDatabase_test and granting the user solves the problem I describe above... I will not close this question as solved, because definitely must work on apache server.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I could solve it, but it took me more time and work than what I tought.

**Fast anwer:** Apache Configuration.  (as @Ahmed Ghiloubi said in his comment)

The solution I post it's relative to ubuntu (the one I'm using right now) or debian based distros. On any other OS running apache, you will have to check how...

I have follow this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart-es)

```sh
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo cp example.com.conf mysite.com.conf
sudo nano mysite.com.conf
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

```sh
sudo a2ensite qapip.test
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Also I had to define a new entry in my hosts configuration

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

```
127.0.0.1   mysite.com
```

After all that... `php bin/phpunit` pointing the `GET` request to `mysite.com` is working as expected